# unsupported JNI version 0xFFFFFFFF

Tags: java, applet, java-native-interface

has anyone encountered that error while using native dll from java code?
Is it the version of the JNI library? or an unresolved dependency?

The error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unsupported JNI version 0xFFFFFFFF required by C:\jnwasapi.dll
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
```

This is a new library I'm using, the others working fine.

Comment: Was the library compiled against a newer version of Java than your existing runtime?

Comment: I think so, you think I need to change the Java version? or could I compile it again?

Comment: I would recompile it again, and ensure that you are linking against your current jdk.  Did the library implement `JNI_OnLoad`?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `jnwasapi.dll`'s `JNI_OnLoad` function is probably returning -1, which is not an expected value. The `JNI_OnLoad` function must return a `jint` with a known constant, such as `JNI_VERSION_1_6`. It's common for `JNI_OnLoad` functions to return -1 if they fail to initialize. For example, it may have tried to load a class which couldn't be found.