# unsupported JNI version 0xFFFFFFFF but only in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface

I try to use a native library in my app. I created a new java project in eclipse and added my own classes. Then I created a new folder "libs" and placed all jar files and the dll there. I added all jars to the java build path and for one jar I set the native library location to MyProject/libs.
Everything is compiled without any problems but if I run the program I will get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unsupported JNI version 0xFFFFFFFF
```

What confused me is that if I compile and run the same project in the console, then everything works fine. So I guess it's a problem of eclipse but I can't figure it out.

Comment: There are several hits in Google (some pointing back to SO) for that error message.  Did none of those help?

Comment: The ultimate answer is two clicks away: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576974/192373

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the library can't be compiled against a newer version of Java than the existing runtime. In that case it would also not working in command line, isn't it?